# Could I merge these two while loops in to only one? Values are not inserted correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, survey

It's for a generated survey form , I want to insert values in my database however I got a problem on inserting values, Here `textarea` values are not being inserted in database. Radio buttons values yes in column radio button but in column for commentary too.  Could I merge these two loops in to only one?  May be it solve my issue? How to do it?

```
if (isset($_POST["bouton11"]))   {

while(isset($_POST[$un])){
    $choix = $_POST["$un"];
    $enregistrer = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix)  VALUES('$choix') ";
    $un++;
    $i++;
    echo"$enregistrer";
    mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer); 
}

while(isset($_POST[$kv])) {
    $comment = $_POST["$kv"];

    $kv++;
    $enregistrer2 = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('$comment')";

    echo"$enregistrer2";
    mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer2);
}

}
```

OK i did edit my code here it is and i will join the survey form code too :

Here is the form

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $Ref =$row["Ref"];
            $Question       =$row["Question"];

            $un++;
            $kv++;

            echo" <tr bgcolor=\"white\">

            <td>$Question position: $un </td>
            <td>
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"3\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"2\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"1\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\"  value = \"0\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"PA\">
            </td>
            <td width = \"60\"> <textarea name =\"$kv\" id =\"un\" rows=\"5\" placeholder=\"PA si pas  applicable\"></textarea> </td> 
        </tr>


    </div>
</div>
"; 

}
```

Here is the part to insert values in DB

```
    if (isset($_POST["bouton11"]))   {

    while((isset($_POST[$un]))||(isset($_POST[$kv]))){
        if(isset($_POST[$un])){
            $choix = $_POST["$un"];
            $comment = $_POST["$kv"];
            $kv++;
            $un++;

            $enregistrer = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara)  VALUES('$choix','$comment') ";



            $i++;
            echo"$enregistrer";
            mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer); 
        }
```

Here is the echo :

```
INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test','test') 
INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test','test') 
INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test','test') 
INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix,Commentara) VALUES('test','test')
```

Now i m kind of confused again because it doesn't take values of radio buttons anymore but only of textarea   so anyone could know how to solve this new issue ?

Comment: You could combine the two arrays into one, and then do `INSERT INTO questionnaire (Choix, Commentara) VALUES (...)`

Comment: ok but then the while will be like ?  while(isset($_POST[$variable1])&&($_POST[$variable2])) ?

Comment: It's going to be a lot of heaving lifting in PHP.  Personally, since it most likely won't affect the performance (or the data inserted), I might even leave the code as it is now.

Comment: but the problem is that i get data mixed between column commentary and choice ( column for radio button values) .  In my echo as you can see : INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('3') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('0') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('3') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('1') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('3')INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('0')INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('3')INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('1')

Comment: It seems strange to be inserting one column at a time.  Are these two datasets somehow related, such that two columns of data should really be inserted at once?

Comment: yes for each radio button set you have a textarea related to it , radio button set for points and textarea for commentary . The survey is like Question // Points (radio button set ) // Commentary (textarea).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  could you help me please .

Comment: I gave you an upvote, I don't know enough PHP to be able to give you an answer quickly.

Comment: Ok ty @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge into one if the two loops have different cycles. You'd have to do an inner and outer loop and do a merge statement within the inner loop.

Comment: ok so could you show me this on my code please because it s kind of hard to understand and i m new on php .

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (isset($_POST["bouton11"]))   {

    while((isset($_POST[$un]))||(isset($_POST[$kv]))){
      if(isset($_POST[$un])
{  $choix = $_POST["$un"];



        $enregistrer = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix)  VALUES('$choix') ";

        $un++;

        $i++;
        echo"$enregistrer";
        mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer); 
 }
else if(isset($_POST[$kv]))
{
 $comment = $_POST["$kv"];

        $kv++;
        $enregistrer2 = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('$comment')";

        echo"$enregistrer2";
        mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer2);
} 
    }
              }
```

Comment: This doesn't combine the two `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Then you use another elseif(((isset($_POST[$un]))AND(isset($_POST[$kv]))) and add both of the code in that contition. Then both insert will be run.

Comment: ok i did try my survey and the echo is still : INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('3') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('1') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('2') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix) VALUES('0') INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('3')INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('1')INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('2')INSERT INTO questionnaire(Commentara) VALUE('0')      . So i m kind of confused

Comment: Ok i added you @HaninderSingh

Comment: still waiting for you to accept me on skype @HaninderSingh

Comment: my skype: harryr891. At that time i am in office. I will accept in the evening